# Problems Deleting Data

Tags: mysql, foreign-key, delete

I'm stuck on trying to delete some information on my MySQL database.

I've never used a database this big and when I developed this application I didn't imagine it would get so big (maybe small for you guys, but for me it's huge).

My thought was:

- I have a table with "mos" Managed Objects (PK `moid`) (Image 1)
- I have a table with "periods" (PK `periodid`) (Image 1)
- I have a table that joins "Period" with the MO (PK moperiodid, FKs `periodid`, `moid`) (Image 1)
- I have 200 tables (the number of tables is variable according to user inputs) that uses the `moperiodid` as FK (Image 2)
- Then, when I want to clean the "historical data", I just delete cascade from MO or from PERIOD.

That was what I thought, but in my real world, it isn't happening well.

Everything works fine for Selects and Inserts, but for the first time I want to begin cleaning data, the main idea was to keep only the last X days (configured according to users input also).

For every day I have 3094555 new moperiods, even the delete of only one is not working:

```
0   13  22:46:19    delete from parser_customer_period_mo where id = 1  Error Code: 1205. Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction    51.169 sec
```

And after every try the InnoDB Writes/Reads per Second goes crazy for 1 hour. (Image 3)

I have no idea about how I'll delete the old information, and this is the small system, I'm building the second one of 30 systems, and the second will have 12 times the amount of data.

**Image 1:**

[image: parser_period]

**Image 2:**

[image: 200 table schema]

**Image 3:**

[image: performance]

Comment: Using 200 tables (which are all the same from what I can see in the picture) is bad - you are storing some data in the table name probably, that should be metadata only - you should have just one table with one more column storing that piece of information. For the deleting.. You can try selecting some subset of data to be deleted and making it in batches -> emulating the cascading in reasonable blocks. Now it seems to just go haywire because all those tables? Whats your `innodb_log_file_size`, `innodb_buffer_pool_size` and RAM available?

Comment: Can you add in the question the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE parser_customer_period_mo ;` and the same for one of the 200 tables: `SHOW CREATE TABLE one_of_the_200 ;`

Comment: @Diogo I moved your workaround to an answer. If you want to ask follow up questions about `on delete cascade` and/or the suitability of InnoDB or MyISAM, please ask a separate question, linking back here if context is important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*<sub>Answer originally added to the question by its author</sub>*

---

I solved the problem for today, but I don't know if my workaround will be enough for the future.

My WorkAround was:

- Deleted all FKs
- Instead of Deleting the older data (~20GB), I selected Into new MyISAM tables (~40GB) and it was fast enough for me.
- Deleted old table and rename the new to the old name.

Aparently I've got a better JOIN performance with MyISAM (All the Queries Users create using the interface will look like this):

```
SELECT 
         SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(m.moname,'LabelName=',-1),',',1) as 'MO Name' ,p.datetime_start,(   ( zzce_SOMECOUNTER.value  +  zzce_SOMEOTHERCOUNTER.value  -  zzce_SOMECOUNTERUra.value  -  zzce_SOMEOTHERCOUNTERUra.value  +  zzce_ANOTHERCOUNTER.value )  ) as value
     FROM
         parser_customer_mos AS m
             INNER JOIN
         parser_customer_period_mo pm ON m.id = pm.moid    
         INNER JOIN
         parser_period p ON pm.periodid = p.id    
          INNER JOIN zzce_SOMECOUNTER ON zzce_SOMECOUNTER.moperiod = pm.id  INNER JOIN zzce_SOMEOTHERCOUNTER ON zzce_SOMEOTHERCOUNTER.moperiod = pm.id  INNER JOIN zzce_SOMECOUNTERUra ON zzce_SOMECOUNTERUra.moperiod = pm.id  INNER JOIN zzce_SOMEOTHERCOUNTERUra ON zzce_SOMEOTHERCOUNTERUra.moperiod = pm.id  INNER JOIN zzce_ANOTHERCOUNTER ON zzce_ANOTHERCOUNTER.moperiod = pm.id  
     WHERE
         m.id IN (SELECT 
                 id
             FROM
                 parser_customer_mos
             WHERE
                 moname LIKE 'ManagedElement=1,RncFunction=1,UtranCell=MGCBHE165OU_%' or moname LIKE 'ManagedElement=1,RncFunction=1,UtranCell=PRCCTA010OU_%' or moname LIKE 'ManagedElement=1,RncFunction=1,UtranCell=PRCCTA055OU_%')
             AND 
      pm.periodid IN (SELECT 
                 id
             FROM
                 parser_period
             WHERE
                 datetime_start BETWEEN '2015-12-12 00:00:00' AND '2015-12-12 17:44:28') ORDER BY datetime_start asc;
```

The Idea is: I have many Counter Groups ("Counter Tables") for Many Objects (MO) many times (PERIODs) a day. Some MOs can have all counters active, and some only a few.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `perf_customer_rnc`.`parser_customer_mos` (
      `id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT '',
      `moname` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'asd' COMMENT '',
      `nename` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'asd' COMMENT '',
      PRIMARY KEY (`moname`, `nename`)  COMMENT '',
      UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC)  COMMENT '')
    ENGINE = InnoDB
    AUTO_INCREMENT = 27358
    DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `perf_customer_rnc`.`parser_period` (
  `id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT '',
  `datetime_start` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '2001-01-01 00:01:00' COMMENT '',
  `datetime_end` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '2001-01-01 00:01:00' COMMENT '',
  `datetime_gmt_start_minutes` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '',
  `datetime_gmt_end_minutes` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '',
  `measurement_elapsed_minutes` SMALLINT(6) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`datetime_start`, `datetime_end`, `datetime_gmt_start_minutes`, `datetime_gmt_end_minutes`)  COMMENT '',
  UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC)  COMMENT '')
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 9904
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1

CREATE TABLE `perf_customer_rnc`.`parser_customer_period_mo` (
  `id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT '',
  `moid` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `periodid` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`moid`, `periodid`)  COMMENT '',
  UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC)  COMMENT '',
  INDEX `moid_idx` (`moid` ASC)  COMMENT '',
  INDEX `periodid_idx` (`periodid` ASC)  COMMENT '',
  CONSTRAINT `mofk`
    FOREIGN KEY (`moid`)
    REFERENCES `perf_customer_rnc`.`parser_customer_mos` (`id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `periodfk`
    FOREIGN KEY (`periodid`)
    REFERENCES `perf_customer_rnc`.`parser_period` (`id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 42331658
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `perf_customer_rnc`.`zzce_CounterName` (
  `moperiod` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `value` INT(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`moperiod`)  COMMENT '',
  CONSTRAINT `fk_CounterName`
    FOREIGN KEY (`moperiod`)
    REFERENCES `perf_customer_rnc`.`parser_customer_period_mo` (`id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `perf_customer_rnc`.`zzce_someOtherCounterName` (
  `moperiod` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `value` VARCHAR(112) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`moperiod`)  COMMENT '',
  CONSTRAINT `fk_someOtherCountername`
    FOREIGN KEY (`moperiod`)
    REFERENCES `perf_customer_rnc`.`parser_customer_period_mo` (`id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `perf_customer_rnc`.`zzce_someOtherCounterName2` (
  `moperiod` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `value` BIT(1) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `value2` BIT(1) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `value3` BIT(1) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `value4` BIT(1) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `value5` BIT(1) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `value6` BIT(1) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `value7` BIT(1) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `value8` BIT(1) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `value9` BIT(1) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `value10` BIT(1) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `value11` BIT(1) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `value12` BIT(1) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `value13` BIT(1) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `value14` BIT(1) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `value15` BIT(1) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `value16` BIT(1) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `value17` BIT(1) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `value18` BIT(1) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `value19` BIT(1) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `value20` BIT(1) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `value21` BIT(1) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `value22` BIT(1) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`moperiod`)  COMMENT '',
  CONSTRAINT `fk_SomeCounterName`
    FOREIGN KEY (`moperiod`)
    REFERENCES `perf_customer_rnc`.`parser_customer_period_mo` (`id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1
```

Host for this first trial is:

Host: Linode 8GB
 - 8 GB RAM
 - 192 GB SSD
 - 6 vCPUs

The bigger will use some other VPS.

my.cnf I didn't did much.

```
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
#
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

# This will be passed to all mysql clients
# It has been reported that passwords should be enclosed with ticks/quotes
# escpecially if they contain "#" chars...
# Remember to edit /etc/mysql/debian.cnf when changing the socket location.
[client]
port            = 7979
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

# This was formally known as [safe_mysqld]. Both versions are currently parsed.
[mysqld_safe]
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice            = 0

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 7979
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
#bind-address           = 127.0.0.1
#
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer              = 16M
max_allowed_packet      = 16M
thread_stack            = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
#max_connections        = 100
#table_cache            = 64
#thread_concurrency     = 10
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_limit       = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M
#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
#general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log             = 1
#
# Error log - should be very few entries.
#
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
#
# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
#log_slow_queries       = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
#long_query_time = 2
#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
#server-id              = 1
#log_bin                        = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days        = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M
#binlog_do_db           = include_database_name
#binlog_ignore_db       = include_database_name
#
# * InnoDB
#
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
#
# * Security Features
#
# Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
# chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
#
# For generating SSL certificates I recommend the OpenSSL GUI "tinyca".
#
# ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
# ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
# ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem



[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet      = 16M

[mysql]
#no-auto-rehash # faster start of mysql but no tab completition

[isamchk]
key_buffer              = 16M

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

Answer (score 0):

`parser_customer_period_mo` is a many-to-many relationship table?  It probably does not need `id`.  (Getting rid of unnecessary indexes helps at some level.)  (This may have *somehow* caused the lock wait timeout.)

200 similar tables -- bad design.  (But seems to be 'necessary' in this situation.)

FKs cost something, but probably that won't explain what you are seeing.

`IN ( SELECT ... )` is an inefficient construct (especially in older versions of mysql), see if you can turn it into a `JOIN`.

`OR` inhibits the use of an index.  (Probably cannot improve on that.)

Change `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to be about 70% of *available* RAM.  This should cut back the I/O a lot.

Comment: Thanks for the response Rick, the SELECT is ok, the DELETE is the problem. `parser_customer_period_mo` ID is the key used in the 200 similar tables. I need those tables because I have many "measurement metrics" that aren't applied to all the MOs all the time, some are filled only in ONCE (a period is a 15 minutes timelapse), so if I didn't do that way I'll leave 166.26e9 empty fields (95 times x 5000 daily measurement results x 350000 mos a day). Mut some of those measurements can be changed to "hourly" or weekly by the click of a user. So I don't know how to improve the design.

Comment: I see your point about 200 tables.  Hard to say what a good design would be.  If you knew which metrics were "rare", they might go into a key-value type table.  But that would lead to other issues.